# Dual Passport Filipino traveling from Saudi Arabia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, filipino-citizens, pakistani-citizens, saudi-arabia

I am a dual citizen by birth, as my mother is a Filipina and I am currently holding a valid Filipino passport. However, due to the laws of my current country of residence, I am required to use my secondary passport to enter/exit the country and as such I usually apply for a temporary visitor visa whenever I travel to the Philippines.

During my last visit to the Philippines, I was advised by the immigration officer at the airport that I do not require a visa and to just present my valid Filipino passport to be granted entry and upon inquiring with the Philippine Embassy in Saudi they advised the same. As such, I would just like to confirm if this would be a viable option for me when traveling to and from Manila and if I would be able to get both passports stamped upon entry to the country.

Secondly, for anyone who has experience traveling with dual passports from Saudi Arabia, do they require you to show a visa upon check-in? And if they do should I present my Filipino passport when they request my visa?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

---

I didn’t specify that I am not a Saudi citizen, I hold a Pakistani passport as well as a Filipino one. So, as a Pakistani, when using that passport I am required to apply for a visa to enter Philippines.

Comment: "As such, I would just like to confirm if this would be a viable option for me when traveling to and from Manila and if I would be able to get both passports stamped upon entry to the country." Why would they stamp both? They would only see the filipino one

Answer (score 5):

> was advised by the immigration officer at the airport that I do not require a visa and to just present my valid Filipino passport to be granted entry

A citizen of a country has the absolute right to reentry, so technically **yes** you only need a piece of citizenship proof and you will be allowed in

> do they require you to show a visa upon check-in?

You could hypothetically show both at the check in desk, but it's at border control that you will have issues

Dual citizenship of Saudi Arabia is extremely discouraged and the border officials **will check** that you have a visa/are visa-free for where you go (from another question here)

Since you can enter the Philipines for 30 days without a visa on your Saudi pasport, if you go direct and stay more than 30 days, there might be a slight chance of you getting caught. Under 30 days, you don't need anything and you can present the Saudi one at exit controls and the Filipino one at entry controls and ask them to stamp both

You can keep doing what you do or get a flight via another GCC country (UAE, Qatar...), claim at the border you go there (you have full freedom of movement to go there anyway) and then take your flight from there with your Filipino... But you need to make sure you also do that on return, ideally through the same transit country

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t specify that I am not a Saudi citizen, I hold a Pakistani passport as well as a Filipino one. So, as a Pakistani, when using that passport I am required to apply for a visa to enter Philippines.

Comment: @JakeDelaCruz, please edit that relevant information into the question.   Otherwise no one will be able to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer the Saudi Arabia part.

The visa will be checked by the airline staff, just show them your Philippines passport and they will update the reservation with it and let you check in.

The immigration officers will not check for the required visas as it's the airlines responsibility.

Just make sure to enter and exit Saudi with the same passport.

As for the dual citizenship, it is not allowed for Saudis to have dual citizenship (it is the law, yet many have dual citizenship, family members included, and they do travel from/to Saudi as I explained above). However, if you are not a Saudi, the dual citizenship is not something you should even think about.